# How to run OpenBLAS source package test from debian/test directory?

Tags: package-management, 20.04, deb, packaging, testing

I need to understand how to run test from debian/test directory for OpenBLAS package.

Currently on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I did the following:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo apt-get build-dep openblas
apt-get source openblas
cd openblas-0.3.8+ds
```

I see 3 files in the `debian/tests` directory:

```
$ ls debian/tests/
control  upstream-testsuite  upstream-testsuite64
```

Which command should I run to execute these `upstream-testsuite` and `upstream-testsuite64`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upstream for Debian means original source code, so we need to run tests from it by using commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install libopenblas-dev libopenblas64-dev

cd ~/Downloads
apt-get source openblas
cd openblas-0.3.8+ds

# create temporary directory
mkdir /tmp/openblas-test
export AUTOPKGTEST_TMP=/tmp/openblas-test

# run 64-bit test
chmod +x debian/tests/upstream-testsuite64
debian/tests/upstream-testsuite64

# run 32-bit test
chmod +x debian/tests/upstream-testsuite
debian/tests/upstream-testsuite
```

Also one can optionally compile benchmarks from the corresponding folder by executing the following commands:

```
cd ~/Downloads/openblas-0.3.8+ds
make -j$(nproc) # you can ignore errors like "undefined reference to `LAPACKE_dgesvd'"
cd benchmark
make -j$(nproc)
```

and then run eigenvalue search benchmark for square matrix to get something like shown below:

> ```
> ./dgeev.goto 1000 10000 1000
> From : 1000  To : 10000 Step = 1000 Job=V
>   SIZE           FLops           Time          Lwork
>   1000 :    10335.25 MFlops :       2.55 Sec : 130000
>   2000 :    15738.12 MFlops :      13.38 Sec : 260000
>   3000 :    19719.22 MFlops :      36.05 Sec : 390000
>   4000 :    22953.55 MFlops :      73.41 Sec : 520000
>   5000 :    26593.65 MFlops :     123.76 Sec : 650000
>   6000 :    29031.12 MFlops :     195.90 Sec : 780000
>   7000 :    30761.17 MFlops :     293.59 Sec : 910000
>   8000 :    33072.54 MFlops :     407.62 Sec : 1040000
>   9000 :    34883.99 MFlops :     550.24 Sec : 1170000
>  10000 :    34694.80 MFlops :     758.90 Sec : 1300000
> ```